# Storing and retrieving data using MySQL for NxN structure in the most optimized and less time consuming way

Tags: javascript, html, database, laravel, database-design

I have a form like below which contains dynamic columns and rows which can be added and deleted as per the user.

[image]

Assuming the number of rows being 50 to 60 and columns upto 10, there are a lot of calculations taking place in the javascript.

I am using MySQL database here and php(Laravel) as backend.
Currently, my table structure is as given below to store the above:-

Table 1 - row_headers (row_id,row_name)
Table 2 - column_headers (column_id, column_name)
Table 3 - book_data ( book_id, row_id, column_id, data_value)

The above set of tables do suffice the data storing, but is extremely slow with respect to Store call as well as get call. While getting the complete data back to the UI there is much load on the database as well as HTML to load the data properly(for loops kill all the time) and also the same is a tedious process.

I want to understand how to optimize the above? What table structure should be used other than the above and what is the best way to reduce the load at backend as well as frontend?

Help appreciated.

Comment: What queries do you use to get the data?

Comment: I am trying simple select query on table3 and then for looping the same on frontend to align the data. Each time for 60 rows and 10 columns structure,my loop runs over 600 times

Comment: Can you post the queries you make? Did you measure their duration?

Comment: Please tell me, is the db structure i am following a proper structure or requires a change? I shall share the queries soon.